# Creating and removing views in java

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am creating lots of view dynamically and adding them to my `RelativeLayout`. I need to keep track of all of these views so I can remove them later, so I add them is an `ArrayList`.  But when I try to remove them all from the layout, they are not all removed.

```
ArrayList<LineView> lineChain = new ArrayList<LineView>();
LineView linkLine;
RelativeLayout wrapper; // Removed params etc.

// Later on in code
// This occurs many times

    linkLine = new LineView(getApplicationContext());
    wrapper.addView(linkLine, rlp);
    lineChain.add(linkLine);
```

This is what I do when I try to remove all of the views. This only happens once:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= lineChain.size() -1; i++) {
    LineView lv = lineChain.get(i);
    wrapper.removeView(lv);
    lineChain.remove(i);
}
```

As I said, the problem is that not all the lines are removed - I havn't managed to work out the pattern for which are deleted and which aren't.

Comment: How about using RelativeLayout#removeAllViews for the wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your remove code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lineChain.size() -1; i++) {
    LineView lv = lineChain.get(i);
    wrapper.removeView(lv);
    lineChain.remove(i);
}
```

The documentation for `ArrayList.remove(int)` function says:

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any
>   subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

When you remove an item at an index `i`, all the remaining elements are shifted to the left. So for example if you remove an element at position 0. The element at position 1 is shifted to position 0 and is never removed (because you are incrementing `i`).

The your code to this:

```
while (!lineChain.isEmpty()) {
    LineView lv = lineChain.get(0);
    wrapper.removeView(lv);
    lineChain.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise they all move to the left.

Comment: I will - there is a time limit before I am allowed to accept :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is while removing the element from the List after the cycle.

You should do something like this:

```
for (LineView lv : lineChain) {
    ((RelativeLayout) namebar.getParent()).removeView(namebar);
}
```

If you want to get rid of all the elements, just reset the list

```
lineChain = new ArrayList<LineView>()
```